# Ruby gem CLI tool, how should I save user settings?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, command-line-interface

I am currently making a CLI tool gem that downloads files from some service and saves them to a specified folder.

I was wondering, what would be the best way to store user settings for it?

For example, the folder to download the files to, the api access token and secret, that kind of thing.

I wouldn't want to ask a user for that input on every run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would read the API stuff from environment variables. Let the users decide if they want to enter it every time or set the variable in a .bashrc or .bash_profile file.

And I would ask for the download folder every time.